# Google Glass voice menu update

Tags: android, menu, google-glass, google-gdk

In my app I'm using `onCreatePanelMenu` to inflate a menu for the voice recognition. When I inflate a simple menu it works fine, but what I want to do is to inflate a different menu depending on what moment of the program the user is.

Using `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `invalidateOptionsMenu()` works fine for gesture menus, put not the same for voice menus.

The code I'm trying to make work is:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {                    // Voice creation menu...
    if (featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS) {
        if(conStateMenu){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.voice_aftcon_menu, menu);
        }else{
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.voice_befcon_menu, menu);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreatePanelMenu(featureId, menu);                // Pass through to super to setup touch menu.
}
```

Where `conStateMenu` changes at some different point during execution. Again, this works fine with gesture menus, but no with voide ones, is there a way to do this (invalidate and load a new menu)?

Thanks!

Comment: `invalidateOptionsMenu` will call `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and not `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: Yeah, i saw that also, but if you go to the android [api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) it also says "The onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs to be displayed." at the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` desription, and well, that is actually working fine.

Comment: And have you tried adding the same login on this function to `onPrepareOptionsMenu`?

Comment: The thing here is that `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` doesn't have the same arguments as `onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu)`so I cant' reference it to `featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS`, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [`Window#invalidatePanelMenu(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#invalidatePanelMenu(int)):

```
getWindow().invalidatePanelMenu(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);
```

This will tell the framework that this feature has been invalidated and needs to be re-created/prepared.